# Facebook pagetab error 500

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a Facebook Page Tab. Everything works as expected, the tab can be added to a user's page, they see an Add Page Tab Dialog, etc.

It doesn't work however, when someone is currently "Using Facebook as" a page that they manage. Looking at Chrome developer tools I see an HTTP 500 internal server error.

To recreate this:

```
<script>

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.0', 
    cookie: true
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function init() {
        console.log("go!");
        FB.ui({
            method: 'pagetab',
            redirect_uri: 'https://www.somedomain.com/widget/?id=3280',
        });
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        init();
    }, 2000);

</script>
```

I'm at a complete loss, any suggestions are greatly welcomed.